# Why am I getting a "Property or Method is not defined" for the variable value instead of the variable name?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a VueJS component that works if I pass through static text, but if I try to bind a variable value, I get a "Property or method is not defined on this instance". But instead of saying it's the prop that's not defined, it's the prop's variable value that is "not defined".

```
HTML:
<section class="reflectionPage" id="reflectionPage">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Independent Learner &amp; International Citizen</h1>
        <h3>Character, Collaboration, Learning Goals</h3>
    </div>
    <reflection-box type="student" imgurl="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech/sepia"></reflection-box>
    <reflection-box type="teacher" v-bind:textbox="teacherComment"></reflection-box>
</section>

VueJS:
// Define a new component called reflection-box
Vue.component('reflection-box', {
    props: ['type', 'imgurl', 'textbox'],
    template: '<div :class="`${type}Reflection`" class="reflection">\
    <h4 v-if="imgurl">{{ type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.slice(1) }} Reflection</h4>\
    <h4 v-else>{{ type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.slice(1) }} Comment</h4>\
    <div class="reflectionBox" :class="`${type}ReflectionBox`"><img v-if="imgurl" :src="imgurl" alt="Reflection Box Image"><p v-if="textbox" v-html="textbox"></p></div>\
</div>'
})

new Vue({
    el: '#reflectionPage'
})
```

If anything, I would expect there to be an error saying that "textbox" is undefined. I don't understand why it's teacherComment that is "undefined"?

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNuy6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that the variable `teacherComment` doesn't exist. If we look at your Vue instance you can see that the only thing it has is the `el` attribute, there is never a `teacherComment` defined. To fix it you need to add it as a data attribute.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#reflectionPage',
  data () {
    return {
      teacherComment: 'The value you wish to give it'
    };
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I don't understand is this:
    <reflection-box type="teacher" v-bind:textbox="teacherComment"></reflection-box>
The variable name I'm trying to bind to is "textbox" and the variable I'm passing through is "teacherComment".

Comment: Actually, that works! Thanks! I guess you need to pass the variable to the root element, and then it can be used by the component. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @theweirdone if you use `v-bind:<attribute>="<property>"` Vue expects what you entered between the quotation marks to be a property, you could also pass a static string by `v-bind:<attribute>="'literal string here'"`but that defeats the purpouse of the `v-bind`